# pandas reindex DataFrame with datetime objects

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas, reindex

Is it possible to reindex a pandas `DataFrame` using a column made up of datetime objects?

I have a DataFrame `df` with the following columns:

```
Int64Index: 19610 entries, 0 to 19609
Data columns:
cntr                  19610  non-null values  #int
datflt                19610  non-null values  #float
dtstamp               19610  non-null values  #datetime object
DOYtimestamp          19610  non-null values  #float
dtypes: int64(1), float64(2), object(1)
```

I can reindex the `df` easily along `DOYtimestamp` with: `df.reindex(index=df.dtstamp)`
and `DOYtimestamp` has the following values:

```
>>> df['DOYtimestamp'].values
    array([ 153.76252315,  153.76253472,  153.7625463 , ...,  153.98945602,
    153.98946759,  153.98947917])
```

but I'd like to reindex the DataFrame along `dtstamp` which is made up of datetime objects so that I generate different timestamps directly from the index. The `dtstamp` column has values which look like:

```
 >>> df['dtstamp'].values
     array([2012-06-02 18:18:02, 2012-06-02 18:18:03, 2012-06-02 18:18:04, ...,
     2012-06-02 23:44:49, 2012-06-02 23:44:50, 2012-06-02 23:44:51], 
     dtype=object)
```

When I try and reindex `df` along `dtstamp` I get the following:

```
>>> df.reindex(index=df.dtstamp)
    TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to long
```

I'm just not sure what I need to do get the index to be of a datetime type. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want reindex.  Somewhat confusingly `reindex` is not for defining a new index, exactly; rather, it looks for rows that have the specified indices.  So if you have a DataFrame with index `[0, 1, 2]`, then doing a `reindex([2, 1, 0])` will return the rows in reverse order.  Doing something like `reindex([8, 9, 10])` does not make a new index for the rows; rather, it will return a DataFrame with `NaN` values, since there are no rows with indices 8, 9, or 10.

It seems like what you want is to just keep the same rows, but make a totally new index for them.  For that you can just assign to the index directly.  So try doing `df.index = df['dtstamp']`.

Comment: Thanks, that does exactly what I need. Somehow it wasn't clear to me that I could assign one of the columns to the index.

Comment: You can also use the `set_index` method