# Resampling or Reindexing Two Columns of Data with different frequencies

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have a dataframe which contains a Time Stamp column, and two data columns (`data1` and `data2`).

The `data1` column spans the entire Time Stamp, while the `data2` column stops about halfway.  When I was collecting my data, both `data1` and `data2` collected data for the same time, except at different frequencies.

I would like the `data2` column to I understand that I should be leaning towards the `resample` or `reindex` functions, but I am unsure how to do this.  My Time Stamp column is an object, while my two data columns are `float64` types.

What is the easiest way for me to accomplish this goal?

I have tried to refer to the following question, but I was having trouble implementing it:
[PANDAS - Loop over two datetime indexes with different sizes to compare days and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43265590/pandas-loop-over-two-datetime-indexes-with-different-sizes-to-compare-days-and)

[image]

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe and your desired output for potential answerers to visualize your problem.

Comment: So the times correspond to the  high frequency data? And your low frequency data is currently not associated with a correct timestamp? (except at 0)

Comment: @GeoMatt22 Correct - my `data1` corresponds to the TimeStamp in my `.csv`, while `data2` does not.  I would like `data2` to span the length of `data1`.

Comment: @GeoMatt22 `data2` is sampled at 10Hz, while `data1` is sampled at 500Hz.

Comment: OK. Before any resampling you would first need to register the 10Hz data (i.e. locate the current data in time). So you need to split off `data2` into a separate dataframe and then assign the appropriate index (note: this is [not a `pd.DataFrame.reindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943478/pandas-reindex-dataframe-with-datetime-objects)).

Comment: Is there a way for me to fill extend `data2` all the way down the entire index of  `data1`, and just fill in everything in between with `NaN`?

Comment: Can you do `df['data2_new'] = np.NaN` then `df.loc[::50, 'data2_new'] = df[:len(df)//50, 'data2']` (where  50 = 500 Hz/10 Hz)?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you're trying to do. My assumptions is that your timestamps are aligned by some multiplier. I've used every 2 minutes in my example, since that's what your example appears to be.  Here's my sample dataframe:

```
df
                        a     b
DATE
2017-05-29 06:30:00   0.0   0.0
2017-05-29 06:31:00   9.0  24.0
2017-05-29 06:32:00  10.0   1.0
2017-05-29 06:33:00  10.0   1.0
2017-05-29 06:34:00   0.0   7.0
2017-05-29 06:35:00   3.0   3.0
2017-05-29 06:36:00   0.0   4.0
2017-05-29 06:37:00   0.0   1.0
2017-05-29 06:38:00   0.0   0.0
2017-05-29 06:39:00   0.0   2.0
2017-05-29 06:40:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:41:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:42:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:43:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:44:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:45:00   2.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:46:00   4.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:47:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:48:00   4.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:49:00   8.0   NaN
```

Extract the misaligned column to it's own dataframe and add a counter column, then add the timedelta to the index, replace the old index, and concatenate the data columns.

```
b = df['b'][:10].to_frame()
b.insert(0, 'counter', range(len(b)))
b.index = b.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x + pd.Timedelta(minutes=b.loc[x].counter))
pd.concat([df['a'], b['b']], axis=1)
                        a     b
DATE
2017-05-29 06:30:00   0.0   0.0
2017-05-29 06:31:00   9.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:32:00  10.0  24.0
2017-05-29 06:33:00  10.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:34:00   0.0   1.0
2017-05-29 06:35:00   3.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:36:00   0.0   1.0
2017-05-29 06:37:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:38:00   0.0   7.0
2017-05-29 06:39:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:40:00   0.0   3.0
2017-05-29 06:41:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:42:00   0.0   4.0
2017-05-29 06:43:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:44:00   0.0   1.0
2017-05-29 06:45:00   2.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:46:00   4.0   0.0
2017-05-29 06:47:00   0.0   NaN
2017-05-29 06:48:00   4.0   2.0
2017-05-29 06:49:00   8.0   NaN
```

It probably goes without saying, but it would be much better to apply correct timestamps to each of the columns when you ingest them.